# Jquery .unbind and .html not working

Tags: jquery

the code below is suppose to remove #approve and #deny and echo what the user has pressed when one of the links are pressed.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#approve').click(function(){
            $('#approve').unbind('click');
            $('#deny').unbind('click');
            $('.rare').html('Approved!');
        });
        return false;
    });
    $('#deny').click(function(){
            $('#approve').unbind('click');
            $('#deny').unbind('click');
            $('.rare').html('Denied!');
        });
        return false;
    });
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="rare">
    <a href id="approve">Approve</a>
    <a href id="deny">Deny</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but it doesnt seem to work, i am new to jquery so i dont understand why it doesnt work. jquery is hosted my google

Comment: Potential issue: using a protocol-less URL (// instead of http:// or https://) will break if you are viewing a local file (you aren't serving this page via a server).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your nesting looks broken, try this:

```
$(function(){

    $('#approve').click(function(){
        $('#approve').unbind('click');
        $('#deny').unbind('click');
        $('.rare').html('Approved!');
        return false;
    });

    $('#deny').click(function(){
        $('#approve').unbind('click');
        $('#deny').unbind('click');
        $('.rare').html('Denied!');
        return false;
    });
})
```

Also, I won't make assumptions about why you're returning false, but if you're wanting to prevent the default `click` event behavior, this is the preferred approach:

```
$('#deny').click(function(e){
    // Absorb click
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#approve').unbind('click');
    $('#deny').unbind('click');
    $('.rare').html('Denied!');
});
```

Cheers

Comment: Yes, this too. Your `return false` should be inside the braces.

Comment: His html is in the question, the a tags have to href so preventDefault is not needed.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Incorrect.  Those hrefs are valid and point to documents on the host server relative the document root.  If he doesn't want to page to attempt to load them when clicked, `preventDefault` (or return false) IS needed.

Comment: @Madbreaks thanks, I did not know that just declaring `href` worked that way.

Answer (score 1):

If this is exactly your code you should be getting an error in firbug/IE's console. You are closing off your ready function `$(function(){` prematurely and have some hanging `})` as well as returning values outside of a function.

Your code should probably be:

```
$(function(){
    $('#approve').click(function(){
            $('#approve').unbind('click');
            $('#deny').unbind('click');
            $('.rare').html('Approved!');
    });
    $('#deny').click(function(){
            $('#approve').unbind('click');
            $('#deny').unbind('click');
            $('.rare').html('Denied!');

    });
});
```

Comment: Everyone mentions firebug on all jquery questions. Not that weird but, isn't anyone using the chrome console?

Comment: @Keyser - I got so used to using Firebug that Chrome's debugger is just a bit un-intuitive for me. There are many guy's in my shop that swear by it though.

Comment: @Keyser Absolutely, because it's far better!

Comment: @Madbreaks you mean chrome or firebug? I myself use chrome's and like it very much. I've only tried firebug once though.